# ReactJs data inside loop empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="row">
     {shopeeship.map(function (key,value) {
       if(key.enabled){
         console.log("yes");
         <div className="col-md-6">
           <div className="form-group">     
              <span className="mr-4 pr-4">
                  <IntlMessages id="shopee.poswm" />
               </span>                                                                       
               <label className="pull-right" title="">
                <Switch/>
               </label>
            </div>
           </div>
      }})}
          </div>
 </div>
```

I have some data and want to loop through it to render some UI. In the above code I tried to loop the data and I checked that if the key enabled then to echo the html value. It successfully prints `yes` in `console log` but the html does not render as expected. Anyone has faced such an issue before? Please help.

Comment: You are mapping over an array and creating HTML, to render that html you need to return it from `map` function.

Comment: @catch me try this simplified solution. i hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636747/6544460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you forgot to return your html from loop

Do this

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="row">
     {shopeeship.map(function (key,value) {
       if(key.enabled){
         console.log("yes");
         return(
           <div className="col-md-6">
             <div className="form-group">     
                <span className="mr-4 pr-4">
                   <IntlMessages id="shopee.poswm" />
                </span>                                                                       
                <label className="pull-right" title="">
                  <Switch/>
                </label>
             </div>
           </div>
         )
      }})}
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: it works, but there will be the "react.development.js:172 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: @catchme Of course. You need to pass an unique prop as key to the first div of your map function. The array that you are mapping through , does it have a unique value? if yes then pass that or else pass the index, which is not considered ideal, as the key prop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified solution using ternary condition and arrow function.

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="row">
    {shopeeship.map((key,value)=> key.enabled ?
      <div className="col-md-6" key={value}>
       <div className="form-group">     
        <span className="mr-4 pr-4">
        <IntlMessages id="shopee.poswm" />
        </span>                                                                       
        <label className="pull-right" title="">
        <Switch/>
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    :null)}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but there will be the "react.development.js:172 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: @catchme check it will work now without warning and let me know if any problem you have.

Comment: @catchme please vote/accept if it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning from map, you can use arrow function instead for implicit return as

```
<div className="col-md-12">
<div className="row">
 {shopeeship.map((key,value) => key.enabled &&
     (<div className="col-md-6">
       <div className="form-group">     
          <span className="mr-4 pr-4">
              <IntlMessages id="shopee.poswm" />
           </span>                                                                       
           <label className="pull-right" title="">
            <Switch/>
           </label>
        </div>
       </div>)
  )}
      </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the html part, map creates a new array and  expects a return value else your array will be filled with null values, hence you would need to return the said html part.